# Is it possible to convert NSString to plain Objective C code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

For example I have

```
NSString *string = @"return sharedInstance;";
```

I have a class method

```
+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

Can I convert that string to plain code and use it in my method? This would be extremely useful for debugging. Suppose I have a method where I want to test some code (Let it be simple return values, Is it possible?) I can just write code for the method and test the new code in runtime.

Comment: you want to compile the objc code at runtime and execute them? better to look about options using scripting language. thats what im using:https://github.com/xlc/CocoJS

Comment: What scripting language are you talking about here? Examples?

Comment: Great! So can I edit the .js file in runtime?

Comment: Btw I'm using a jailbroken device, so I dont care what permissions it needs, what private methods it uses etc. @xlc0212

Comment: A cool hack would be to embed the compiler into your executable. It's feasible, but you'd better off trying python or some other scripting language.

Comment: Any more hints? Im a noob in these kind of stuff :P

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? - Perhaps there's a better way than using dynamic code.

Comment: Hey, buddy, i'm trying to achieve the same thing. Did CocoJS help you? Or maybe you found a better solution?

Comment: Well, NSSelectorFromString helped me a lot. I wrote down a few methods in my class to access other methods from other classes dynamically. Like i have an alert where i can input the selector Ex @"mySelector:" and then make a certain instance of a class perform a certain task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've described isn't exactly possible. But there is support for certain things, eg, the ability to instantiate classes and invoke methods (theoretically) with strings:

`NSClassFromString` allows you to instantiate classes based on a passed string.

`NSSelectorFromString` allows you to invoke or 'call' a method based on passed string.

The string can be determined dynamically at run-time.

Based on your comments this is apparently not what you're interested in (despite the fact I think it does actually address your question). One thing you can do (it's not native Obj-C, but I think it is pertinent given some of the comments) is to inject `JavaScript` into a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thats not what I want, I know about this

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: This is the closest thing doable in Objective-C.

Comment: You can inject JavaScript into a UIWebView. That may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, if NSSelectorFromString can be changed in runtime it would be of great help

Comment: Yes the string for either of these methods can be determined at run time. You could for example invoke a method on a class where both the class and method are determined as the result of strings fetched from a web service.

Answer (score 6):

Objective C on iOS is a compiled language; The code is interpreted and translated to machine code long before you run your application. Running objective C in a dynamic manner like this is not possible. For this you're gonna need a dynamic language.